# Getting back Windows 10 recovery which has windows 7 recovery

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

Initially I used regback registry to fix USBPCap USB not working problem . After sometime It gave 0xc000021a BSOD  . So i used Windows 10 iso to repair and messed it up with bootrec and bcdedit commands.
Now Windows 10 iso opens Windows 7 recovery options.
Tried SFC and dism.
I am able to boot PC only by disabling driver signature enforcement . Which I can select only from 0x0000001 error  after multiple restarts from BSOD.
Debugging minidump showed ntoskrnl to be causing 0xc000021a error. Reset and restore not an option
Incidents may not be related
Also startup repair using windows 10 iso which shows Windows 7 logo and UI gives OS mismatch error.

Comment: Not answer to your question, but wouldn't it be easier to just back up your stuff and do clean reinstall? Fixing windows is usually pain in the ass.

Comment: No I want all my data and software. I am a software geek of sort. So I need all my customizations. And currently I don't have any HDD with me. But I have lot of data. Cloud is off options. Because in India ,Internet Charge of backing up all my data = 5 times the price of my whole PC. Thanks call help.

Comment: Got recovery back to normal by setting boot mode to UEFI in BIOS.
Still couldn't fix 0xc000021a though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got recovery back to normal by setting boot mode to UEFI in BIOS.